# Pyspark databricks read header from first file

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to read airline dataset in databricks.

```
Path in databricks ->  /databricks-datasets/airlines
```

There are multiple files present under this folder - starting from part-00000 and so on.

**Only part-00000 file has header information present. Other files don't have header information**

I am trying to read all the files using the following command

```
df= spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-*")
```

For some reason it is not pulling header information from first file part-00000. Is there a way to pull header information from part-00000 file as the other files don't have header info.

Thanks!

Comment: I don’t know they the * wildcard works with pyspark. That might be the issue. If that’s the case, then you would put your read command in a ```for i in range``` and then format I into five characters and insert it into the file path string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can first read the csv partition file that contains the headers:

```
df = spark \
    .read \
    .format("csv")\
    .option("header", "true") \
    .load("/databricks-datasets/airlines.csv/part-00000")
```

Then save the schema:

```
csv_schema = df.schema
```

And you can now read the all the partitions using the schema `csv_schema`:

```
df = spark \
    .read \
    .format("csv")\
    .schema(csv_schema) \
    .load("/databricks-datasets/airlines.csv")
```